# PHP5 object instances are in server RAM or on client's computer RAM

Tags: php

PHP5 object instances while the application is running are in server RAM or on client's computer RAM ?!

what about sessions ?!

sorry for this dumb question, I need to know this so I know how to manage memory.

If I'm getting the idea of PHP applications wrong plz correct me.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to "manage memory" in PHP.

Comment: @meagar I didn't mean memory management literally, I just wanted to point that this situation could change the way I used memory.

Comment: But you *can't* change the way you use memory in PHP. You either use the language and let it manage its own memory, or you don't use PHP. There is no middle ground, and no point worrying about it. Memory management is so far below your level of concern as a PHP developer that you not only don't have to worry about it, you can't directly affect it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP objects are stored in the server's RAM. Sessions are usually stored on the servers hard disk (in the `/tmp` directory) but current sessions will use up some of the server's RAM too. Everything PHP related will be on the server. The client only deals with HTML, CSS, JavaScript and any plugins (like Flash).

Comment: when exactly the object gets erased from the memory ?

Comment: The PHP object will be freed from memory when the current PHP execution ends. This is normally when the page has been sent to the user. You can `unset` variables to free memory and they may be garbage collected before the script ends. In PHP 5.3 you can also call [gc_collect_cycles()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) to force it to try to free memory.

Answer (score 2):

sessions and objects are stored in your servers RAM

Answer (score 2):

php runs on the server ... when php has completed processing, the result is delivered to the client

Answer (score 2):

PHP executes on the server side.  Objects created are in server memory.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about "traditional" PHP apps, then most of the work happens server side. Stuff like HTML5 databases, client caches etc can muddy the waters (so thought I'd throw 'em in for good measure.